# Paste data from excel to website, click "track"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have an excel sheet with 1000's of tracking numbers for Canada Post which I need to copy and paste the data from excel to the website, click on the track button and then write down the delivery date. Doing this manually is painful so I would like to automate it. Currently I am using Python and am able to open the spreadsheet and select the data. **I am currently stuck on how to paste the data and perform the "click".** I believe that once the website finds the information that I know how to (start at least) gather the information with requests and then use beautifulsoup to sort it for me.

I have attached the source code from Canada Post as to where I believe the correct onclick command is. I am unsure how to paste the data but I believe I found the "form" in their code (link below). Hopefully someone can quickly point me in the right direction. Thanks again for your guidance for such a novice.

Link to "Form" [Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEKBX.jpg)

[image]

```
<input id="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:submit_button" name="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:submit_button" type="submit" value="Track" 
onclick="if(typeof window.clearFormHiddenParams_tapByTrackSearch_trackSearch=='function')
{clearFormHiddenParams_tapByTrackSearch_trackSearch('tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch');}if(typeof window.getScrolling!='undefined')
{oamSetHiddenInput('tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch','autoScroll',getScrolling());}" class="button margintop20 marginright">
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, well I realized that my main problem was that there was a colon ":" in both the name and id for the elements that I was trying to find. Instead of searching for the entire name or id I used the contains function (not sure if it's actually called a function) and it work well.

In the end I was able to use the following code:

```
    drivernd_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').send_keys("RN231000000CA")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "submit_button")]').send_keys(chr(13))
```